# Node.js and Socket.IO notification warning for server restart

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, notifications

*I'm sorry if this is the wrong stack for this question.*

I have a Node.js server running on Heroku. Whenever I commit something, the server restarts. I want to warn the users that there's going to be a restart so that I don't completely ruin their experience. Just a simple notification with the text "Server restart in X minutes".

Let's say I have the client side all set up and a Socket.IO emit is all that's needed for the notification to be shown. **How would I do that?** I thought of having some sneaky function on the client side that would make the server emit the notification, but I'm afraid it can be easily exploited.

Comment: Do you have some kind if authentication and authorization in place? Surely you could restrict this administrative function from non-admin clients

Comment: @cubrr no, I don't have. If the function requires a secret code word that I check on the server, would that be enough?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to detect the `SIGTERM` signal that Heroku sends to your app to shut it down, and once that signal is detected, to emit the notification to every connected client:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  // send your signal
})
```

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown

However, a better user experience is just to ensure that users never even know your server restarted. With node this shouldn't be difficult, you only need:

1. To ensure your process ends and starts quickly (quickly being a few seconds)
2. To ensure your clients all have reconnection logic (this is built into socket.io so you shouldn't have to do anything)
3. Optionally, to turn on preboot, which will make the delta between one server going down and another coming up be close to zero (`heroku features:enable -a myapp preboot`)

   - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot#enabling-and-disabling-preboot

Comment: I agree, but I don't have reconnection logic and I believe I can't achieve it because there's data on the server that is essential for the user and is changing real-time (it's a game) and when the server restarts, that data is gone. Also, I'd like to warn users about the restart myself several minutes beforehand, not several seconds. Is there an easy way to do _that_? I appreciate your answer, though!

Comment: try using something like Redis to hold some data eventually some data will be lost you could just work reconnect to fallback server until primary is up and stable. client should handle reconnection to fallback server not server. Primary server should just yell "hey I'm about to shut down"..in game archtectures there are different servers for each component of the game (map,chat,etc)

Comment: There's no way to notify users about the restart several minutes beforehand.

I don't believe what you'd like to do is possible as long as you're keeping state in the server process itself (vs in some sort of storage, like redis).